# Using multiple functions in the same field in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I want to use multiple functions on a field and store the result into one field, like this:

```
left(Campagne,len(Campagne)-4) and Replace(Campagne,'%2f','/') and PurgeChar (Campagne,'.g.c') as Campagne;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either nest functions, or use preceding loads to obtain what you wish. Depending on your load script, preceding loads are often neater and somewhat easier to follow, but result in slightly more script.

**Preceding load**:

```
MyTable:
LOAD
   left(Campagne, len(Campagne) - 4) as Campagne;
LOAD
   Replace(PurgeChar(Campagne,'.g.c'),'%2f','/') as Campagne
FROM ...
```

**Nesting**:

```
MyTable:
LOAD
    left(replace(purgechar(Campagne,'.g.c'),'%2f','/'), len(replace(purgechar(Campagne,'.g.c'),'%2f','/'))-4) as Campagne
FROM ...
```

As you can see in the nesting example, as you're using `len` you end up repeating your operations twice.